# how to customize default view for linkItemCollection in EPiServer

Tags: episerver

I'm using EPiServer version 11 and I have requirement that when property of type linkItemCollection is rendered using PropertyFor() method, I need to add some custom attribute ( based on condition if target is blank ) to generated hyperlink.

```
@Html.PropertyFor(x => x.Layout.LinksCollection)
```

I have idea of creating a custom view under DisplayTemplates in view and adding new view. My query is how can i  get default template for linkItemCollection to get it started ?

Answer (score 1):

The easy option would be to o it yourself and not worry about the Property for,  the only slight issue is that you may not get inline editing to work.

https://www.jondjones.com/learn-episerver-cms/episerver-developers-tutorials/episerver-properties/how-to-display-a-list-of-links-in-episerver/

To go with your route

```
[UIHint("MyView")]
[Display(
    GroupName = SystemTabNames.Settings,
    Order = 100)]
public virtual LinkItemCollection MyProperty{ get; set; }
```

In Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates add a template MyView.cshtml

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the PropertyFor you could take full control of the rending yourself.

```
    // FullRefreshPropertiesMetaData asks on-page edit to reload the page 
    // to run the following custom rendering again after the value has changed.
    @Html.FullRefreshPropertiesMetaData(new []{ "RelatedContentLinks" })

    // EditAttributes enables on page-edit when you have custom rendering.
    <p @Html.EditAttributes(m => m.CurrentPage.RelatedContentLinks) >
    @if (Model.CurrentPage.RelatedContentLinks != null)
    {        
        <span>See also:</span>
        foreach (LinkItem item in Model.CurrentPage.RelatedContentLinks)
        {
            <a href="@UrlResolver.Current.GetUrl(item.Href)">@item.Text</a>        }
    }
    </p>
```

Taken from the [EPi documentation](https://world.episerver.com/documentation/developer-guides/CMS/learning-path/listings-and-navigation/#LinkCollections)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your input on this.

I managed to resolve this as below.

```
 public static MvcHtmlString LinkItemCollectionFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
        {
            MvcHtmlString result = PropertyExtensions.PropertyFor(html, expression);
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(result.ToString().Replace("target=\"_blank\"", "target=\"_blank\" rel=\"noopener noreferrer\""));
        }
```

Hope, it helps someone.